# How to make GitLab CI/CD DIND use Insecure Registries

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have the following in my GitLab CI/CD config:

```
image: docker:19.03.0

services:
  - name: docker:19.03.0-dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=My_IP:4567"]

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN My_IP:4567
```

Everything I can find claims this should allow insecure registries in my docker container however,  this does not appear to be true (anymore?). As I can see in the end of the run log:

```
  Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN My_IP:4567
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://My_IP:4567/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this may be happening? Sadly I have tried many many different iterations of this test file and I just started making loads of minor changes and nothing has worked. I have even tried older container versions but everything is a no go, I have never been able to get the insecure registry to be added.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to handle it?  I have the same issue.

Comment: Running into the exact same issue. The answers below didn't resolve it unfortunately...

Answer (score 3):

For multiple insecure registry

```
services:

  - name: docker:19.03.0-dind

    command:

      [

        '--insecure-registry=172.16.208.77:30551',

        '--insecure-registry=172.16.208.77:30552'
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
command: ["--insecure-registry=My_IP:4567"]
```

by

```
command: ["--insecure-registry","My_IP:4567"]
```

Also make sure that the first line specifies the right image as well as some env vars:

```
image: docker:19.03-dind

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

services:
  - docker:19.03-dind
# .... rest of your config
```

Comment: I made the edits suggested and Insecure Registries still only has "127.0.0.0/8" and errors out the same as before. I did try adding your "/certs" just in case and no change. I am fairly certain Gitlab had a doc claiming using a blank CERTDIR var was what should be done when not using TLS.